# Truncate (using ROUND) has stopped working after changing column data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use the following query on the SQL Server 2008 database of a 3rd party product to generate some reports.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(Price),0,1) AS SumNetPrice FROM Transactions
```

Eg

```
 SUM(Price): 1.2345678
 ROUND(SUM(Price),0,1): 1
```

This has worked fine until now and removed all of the decimal places. In fact curiously the result was truncated even if I didn't specify the 3rd parameter as per the MSDN information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx on the ROUND function.

The 3rd party company has now changed the data type of the Price column from 'real' to decimal(22, 7). Unfortunately this now means that I always get 7 decimal places even when I use the truncate option of the ROUND function. So now I get:

```
 ROUND(SUM(Price),0,1): 1.0000000
```

Shouldn't the ROUND(expression,0,1) truncate the result so I don't get any decimal places? How can I remove these decimal places from the result in the SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(SUM(Price),0,1) AS DECIMAL(22,0)) AS SumNetPrice FROM Transactions
```

Comment: I see, so I need to CAST the answer. Well that's certainly not clear from the MSDN documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it working the way it worked earlier is to Convert the type from decimal to real. Here is your updated query to get desired output.

```
select Cast(ROUND(SUM(Price),0,1) as Real) AS SumNetPrice FROM Transactions
```

Comment: I'm afraid Holger just beat you to the answer but I've upvoted your alternative suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the up vote. Yes its up to you to choose the best solution. I see it from your code point of view casting it to real could solve any other hidden problem and let your app run as it is. If you look from client point of view (holger answered from that point). You don't want to mess with the type that you receive.

Comment: Yes good to have both alternatives. As it happens the Query is just used in a Reporting Tool rather than part of a large app so the resulting data type isn't that important but it's good to know the issues involved.